# Mounting Apple Hitachi HTS545050B9A302 on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, mac, compatibility

I have recently acquired a new desktop computer after burring my old mac book pro. I wanted to put some old parts to use and I tried to plug the mac's HDD into the desktop computer but it doesn't appear as a usable device. I was able to recover my files with HFSExplorer and i can see everything there, I can also see it in the device manager. However i can't do anything else, the drivers appears to be up to date (but it claims they're from 2006) and i can't find any alternatives on the internet. 
Anyone knows what can i do to make it available?